# How to deal with boxed and chained error on rust?

Tags: error-handling, rust, hyper, reqwest

Il have many proxies uri (http and socks5) and i'm using reqwest for sending some http request throught theses proxies and i wanna drop a proxy if he didn't work.

```rust
for proxy in proxies {
    let proxy = match Proxy::all(proxy_url) {
        Ok(proxy) => proxy,
        Err(e) => {
            eprintln!("creating proxy failed! {:?}", e);
            continue;
        }
    };

    let client = match Client::builder()
    .proxy(proxy)
    .build()

    let client = match client {
        Ok(client) => client,
        Err(e) => {
            eprintln!("building client failed! {:?}", e);
            continue;
        }
    }

    loop {
        match client.get(&config.endpoint).send().await {
            Ok(_) => {}
            Err(e) => {
                if e.is_proxy_error() { // this method doesn't exist
                    eprintln!("Dropping proxy...");
                    break;
                } else {
                    eprintln!("client error! {:?}", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And i got many kind of `Reqwest::Error`

```
reqwest::Error { kind: Request, url: "http://example.com/", source: hyper::Error(Connect, "socks connect error: Invalid response version") }
reqwest::Error { kind: Request, url: "http://example.com/", source: hyper::Error(Connect, "socks connect error: Proxy server unreachable") }
reqwest::Error { kind: Request, url: "http://example.com/", source: hyper::Error(Connect, "socks connect error: Connection refused") }
reqwest::Error { kind: Request, url: "http://example.com/", source: hyper::Error(Connect, "socks connect error: Connection reset by peer (os error 104)") }
```

The error message is explicit in most case, but how can i handle each of them differently ?
The `reqwest::Error` have `inner` field which is private so i cant access him.
And if i get the source of the `reqwest::Error`, i just have an `Box<syn Error>` which i cant treat like a `hyper::Error`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can downcast the result of `Error::source()` to a concrete error type, e.g.

```
use std::error::Error;

...

    Err(reqwest_error) => {
        let hyper_error: Option<&hyper::Error> = reqwest_error
            .source()
            .unwrap()
            .downcast_ref();
        ...
    }
```

This code uses `unwrap()` to extract the error from the `Option` returned by `source()`. If you can't guarantee that the error will always have a source, you should use some conditional way to unwrap the source, e.g.

```
let hyper_error: Option<&hyper::Error> = reqwest_error
    .source()
    .and_then(|e| e.downcast_ref());
```